# Как отключить кэш для firefox при ajax запросе?

Tags: javascript, ajax

вот код который принимает json объект, из него я рендерю url изображений
проблема в том что в ff 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

код запроса

```
$.ajax({
         url: 'url',
         type: 'GET',
         dataType: 'json',
         data: "obj",
         cache: false, 
        success: function (data) {///do some}

                });
```

хотя параметр cache: false должен вроде отключать кеширование

Comment: Добавляйте на сервере правильные HTTP-заголовки, которые отключают кэш

Comment: headers: {
     'Cache-Control': 'no-cache' 
}, не помогает

Comment: Вы точно написали это именно на сервере?

Comment: нет, у меня нет доступа к серверу, я просто беру по урлу json и уже работаю с ним

Comment: Ну тогда вполне логично, что закэшировалось, если сервер простит браузер закэшировать всё. Идите просите администратора сервера отключить кэширование